# What's a good place to put your module @imports?

Tags: objective-c, xcode5

So I am using the new `@import` module syntax introduced with the latest Xcode - I still wonder where the best place is to put them. Before, I would place library imports and very important categories in the `.pch` file, but now that's not necessary anymore (at least not for the native frameworks). My first idea was to create a `modules.h` file and do all the imports there, then include that `modules.h` file in the `AppDelegate` - but this doesn't seem right. Also, importing in the first place you need it doesn't make sense either, since you might use it in different places.

This is in fact a question about "best practices" which is - of course - a little subjective. But I think this affects a lot of people and the overall project structure. So please share your solution to this.

Comment: Just import where ever you use it. What's the problem with that?

Comment: Please inform yourself about @import before you comment.

Answer (score 2):

it sounds like you weren't doing it the best way before, In general you want as few symbols available at any one time. For a few different reasons:
less likely to make a mistake with symbols that have the same name but different values, or types... and for reasons that the compiler has to import less crap into each compilation unit.

I am not an expert on how `@import` has changed the compiler semantics of preprocessing and compiling, but I suspect you should still basically import things as close to the point that they will be used as possible.

I generally will not generally import any class's headers into another class's .h file.
in a .h I will forward declare any classes with `@class SomeCLass` and only include enough headers to satisfy the c/c++ types that I use as ivar/properties.  The only exception to that being if I need to include a superclass's header or another .h for a protocol.

the rest of the includes go into the .m

I like to keep my pch pretty spartan, but if you have some utility categories or a widely used library you *could* include stuff in there, I tend not to... but in a smaller project you probably wont run into problems... you will run into indexing problems in projects with hundreds of source files, especially if you have some Objective-C++ units. That will end up hurting code completion and live syntax checking.

Comment: sorry i meant just as a comment, but I went a little blow hard.

Comment: +1 I would only import things in the prefix header that I use in almost all of my source files. That's why UIKit is imported by default in iOS app projects. I added the Lumberjack logging library myself, and that's it.

Comment: Thanks I already do it like that and only use the .pch if it's really needed. But this doesn't answer what's best practice for @import because it's completely different from #import

Comment: @jimpic, I know how it is different from the user's perspective, but don't know from the compilers perspective... that is I am sure `@import` is better than #import from a linking/speed perspective, because there is a map in the module, but I don't know if it is so much better that it doesn't matter at all, and you can just jam everything you will ever use in the pch... I suspect that all the same guidelines hold and in places where you are a little sloppy it will just matter less.

Comment: +1 for `@class MyClass` in `.h` and `@import "MyClass.h"` in `.m`